# How to pass Client Side data to Server Side using Ember.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ember.js

I'm studying Ember.js myself and I'm stuck with a problem I'm creating a sample app and I need to send the client side values to Server Side but I dont know how to do that I know the traditional way like the below code

```
function create() {
        var data = {
            'EmailID': $('#emailid').val(),
            'password': $('#password').val()
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/EmberNew/Home/Create',
            type: 'POST',
            data:data,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("hi");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

but In Ember i dont Know How to do that my current code is given below

```
//Application

App = Em.Application.create();

//Model

App.Users = Em.Object.extend({
    name: null,
    password:null
});

//View
App.UserTextField = Em.TextField.extend({
    insertNew: function () {
        App.alertController.alertDetails();
    }
});

App.PassTextField = Em.TextField.extend({
    insertNew: function () {
        App.alertController.alertDetails();
    }
});

//controller

App.AlertController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    content: [],
    username: '',
    password: '',
    alertDetails: function () {
        var me = this;
        var username = me.get("username");
        var password = me.get("password");
        alert('The User Name Is' + 'username' + 'And Password Is' + 'password');
    }
});
App.alertController = App.AlertController.create();
```

I got the textbox values from alertDetails function and how can I pass them to server side

Comment: are you interested in something like ember-data or do you want a "how to roll my own" ?

Comment: @ToranBillups I heard about ember-data but I'm not sure using it in apps with out a stable release so I'm trying to do something like "how to roll my own"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
App.Record = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: '',
  other: ''
}).reopenClass({
  records: [],
  find: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/records/",
      type: "GET",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: function() {
        //if you want to call this often and need to clear + reload it
        return self.records.clear();
      },
      success: function(results) {
        var result;
        for (_i = 0, _len = results.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            result = results[_i];
            self.records.push(self.records.addObject(App.Record.create(result)));
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        return alert("error: failed to load the records");
      }
    });
    return this.records;
  }
});
```

Now that you have your model setup, you can call it from your route model hook

```
App.RecordsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
    return App.Record.find();
    }
});
```

The find method returns an empty array right away, your template is then bound to it. When the ajax call returns w/ success and you update that array the handlebars template will update it for you w/out any DOM or jQuery glue code